# Верстка таблицами или блоками

Tags: html

Здраствуйте, хотела поинтересоваться, какая верстка удобнее табличная или блочная, делала сайт divами - при любых изменениях в коде все остальные блоки "плывут". Вот, думаю, не проще ли табличная верстка?

Comment: Верстайте не сферические страницы в вакууме, а шаблоны для cms. Для любой cms. Ответ сам придёт, и он будет более качественным, чем мы тут можем дать.

Comment: блочная верстка более правильная, чем табличная. как-то раньше сам верстал сайт с табличной версткой, так начальник меня раскритиковал за это. Дивы более правильное решение, при навыке и более удобные...

Comment: табличная легче, но она уже не в "моде"

Comment: понятно, попробую научиться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Верстка удобна та, которая вам доступна по знаниям! Если знания позволяют выровнять многоуровневую вложенность div'ов, тогда блочная. Если же вы не справляетесь с этим, используйте табличную верстку! Что относительно удобства, удобнее таблицами. Профессионально конечно блоками.

Comment: Если так вопрос ставить, то **удобнее** вообще без верстки :-)

Answer (score 1):

всё зависит от структуры, макет сайта лучше верстать дивами, они более гибкие. если же контент подразумевает таблицу, тогда разумеется таблицу. да и таблицами сложновато будет реализовать резиновую верстку. так что наберитесь терпения и осваивайте верстку дивами.

Answer (score 1):

Мода не мода, когда-то и я табличной верстала, а на блочную смотрела как на что-то очень трудное. Но со временем... Короче я теперь вообще не представляю как можно заявлять что табличная вёрстка проще?! Нет ничего проще и быстрее чем вёрстка блоками. Там понять-то не так много нужно - `margin,padding,float,clear,position`... :-)

Comment: Полина, вы не вполне правы. Там надо чуть больше понять.

Comment: @Syabrowka, так я ж и написала в конце хитрое многоточие. :-))) Ну что ещё можно добавить? Информацию о том как ведут себя плавающие блоки относительно друг друга? Вооо, можно ещё display добавить в список. :-)

Comment: ага :) div { display: table } и div { display: table-cell } :)
а чё? зато не таблица :) ну типа не таблица :)